# How to Make Letters Like This?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, effects, adobe-fireworks

I'd like to know how to make these in photoshop or fireworks, but with a slight preference for fireworks. If I can find a tutorial in photoshop, I can probably get it to work in fireworks.

[image]

What is this type of effect called? Is it a particular font they are using?

Comment: Dunno if it's a font or not. Assuming that it wouldn't be a long text or multiple texts and also assuming that I wanted to make exactly the same thing: I would probably go to the Blending options to set Inner bevel as a guide, and then use Pen tool to cut out the lines.

Comment: Not the same font, but this commercial package do something near : Shades http://www.typography.com/fonts/font_overview.php?productLineID=100023&path=head

Answer (score 7):

I'm 99.999999% sure the example you posted is just a typeface that's like that. If you want to achieve a rough approximation in Photoshop, it's possible using the Bevel and Emboss Layer Style. The key is the custom contour.

[image: Bevel and Emboss]

The best way to do something like that would be to use a font with the effect baked in, or draw custom shapes... probably in Illustrator (it's far better at things like this).

Comment: Yes, Illustrator if Bevel and Emboss won't do it.. object->path->offset path is a godsend

Comment: Yeah. The Pathfinder panel in Illustrator is also great for this kind of thing.